# How to deal with DATE column of multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, inner-join, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have 5 tables namely transaction, receipt, payment, wutran, mydates.
mydates table contains dates.It has only one single column that is dt.
and all remaining tables have two columns namely date,amount.
Now I have to calculate sum of the amounts from these 4 tables group by the 'dt' which is the column of mydates.
my query is as follows:

```
select 
m.dt,
(SUM(t.amount)+SUM(r.amount)+SUM(p.amount)+SUM(w.amount)) as sum_amount
from 
transaction t,
receipt r, 
payment p, 
wutran w 
inner join 
mydates m 
on t.[date]=m.Dt and r.[date]=m.Dt
and p.[date]=m.Dt and w.[Date]=m.Dt group by m.Dt
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "t.date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "r.date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "p.date" could not be bound.
```

Can anyone help me out with this error......

Answer (score 1):

`Error` is because of `JOIN` will applicable only for `wutran`  and `mydates`, You can try other condition with **`Where`** but it's not recommended.

Try this

```
  SELECT m.dt,(SUM(t.amount)+SUM(r.amount)+SUM(p.amount)+SUM(w.amount)) AS sum_amount 
  FROM transaction t,receipt r, payment p, wutran w 
       INNER JOIN mydates m ON w.[Date] = m.Dt 
  WHERE t.[date] = m.Dt AND r.[date] = m.Dt AND p.[date] = m.Dt 
  GROUP BY m.Dt
```

Or You have to **`JOIN`** all the Tables

```
  SELECT m.dt,(SUM(t.amount)+SUM(r.amount)+SUM(p.amount)+SUM(w.amount)) AS sum_amount 
  FROM transaction t
        JOIN mydates m on t.[date] = m.Dt
        JOIN receipt r on r.[date] = m.Dt
        JOIN payment p on p.[date] = m.Dt
        JOIN wutran w  on w.[Date] = m.Dt 
  GROUP BY m.Dt
```

Comment: This answer would be considerably better if you also explained the problem in the OP and how your query fixed it.

Comment: IIUC, I posted this comment before you edited the answer. Looks fine now - thanks! (+1ed)

Comment: I don't think this rewrite will give the result OP is looking for. Joining like this will create duplicate rows that is aggregated unless the date values are unique in `receipt,payment,wutran`. And likely they are not.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I'll look it into my solution and ill update it

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.dt,SUM(t.amount+r.amount+p.amount+w.amount) as sum_amount 
from transaction t
    inner join mydates m on t.[date]=m.Dt
    inner join receipt r on r.[date]=m.Dt
    inner join payment p on p.[date]=m.Dt
    inner join wutran w  on w.[Date]=m.Dt 
group by m.Dt
```

Comment: You left a comma after the first table in the `FROM`

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.dt,(SUM(t.amount)+SUM(r.amount)+SUM(p.amount)+SUM(w.amount)) as sum_amount 
 from transaction t,
      receipt r, 
      payment p, 
      wutran w ,
      mydates m 
 where t.[date]=m.Dt and r.[date]=m.Dt
 and p.[date]=m.Dt and w.[Date]=m.Dt 
 group by m.Dt
```